# "ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected - got CLOB" on varchar2 field

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle10g

I'm using a LINQ to query a string field which is defined as follows:

```
"RUT" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE
```

Visual Studio generated a Producer class with the following property:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.String RUT
{
    get
    {
        return _RUT;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_RUT != value)
        {
            OnRUTChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("RUT");
            _RUT = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("RUT");
            OnRUTChanged();
        }
    }
}
private global::System.String _RUT;
partial void OnRUTChanging(global::System.String value);
partial void OnRUTChanged();`
```

I try to run the following code:

```
var producer = db.Producers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.RUT == rut);
```

I get an exception saying

> {"ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB"}

I don't understand how CLOB got involved in this.
Anyone care to shed some light?

My specs:

- Visual Studio 2010
- MVC 4
- Oracle database 10g
- Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio

Comment: do a google search on the exact error

Comment: I did. Obviously other people received the error but didn't find anyone with a varchar2 field being interpreted as CLOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long journey, what resolved my problem was updating Oracle Developer Tools for VS to its newest version (ODTwithODAC121021).

Hope this will help make the world a better place. :)